# access child action parameter in its view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, http-request-parameters, child-actions

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and Index view goes like

```
...
@Html.Action("Index", "BController", new { HasEditPermission = true })
...
```

BControler goes like

```
public class BController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

and this Index Partial view goes like

```
...
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["HasEditPermission"]) && bool.Parse(Request.Params["HasEditPermission"]))
{
 // some html rendering
}
...
```

here when I do `Request.Params["HasEditPermission"]` in the partial view, I get null.. but if I include `HasEditPermission` as a parameter to my `Index` action of `BController` then I get the value..

I think, I am not getting it from `Request.Params` because actual request is to `AController` `Index` action which doesn't include this parameter.

But I am wondering how is it binding the value to HasEditPermission parameter of Index action(suppose if I have it there) of BController?

Please could someone tell me how do I access it directly in the view? (I am aware using ViewBag in Index is an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ValueProvider.GetValue("HasEditPermission").RawValue` to access the value.

**Controller:**

```
public class BController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         ViewBag.HasEditPermission = Boolean.Parse(
              ValueProvider.GetValue("HasEditPermission").RawValue.ToString());

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
...
@if (ViewBag.HasEditPermission)
{
    // some html rendering
}
...
```

**Update:**

`Request.Params` gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items not RouteValues.

In

```
@Html.Action("Index", "BController", new { HasEditPermission = true })
```

`HasEditPermission` is a `RouteValue`.

you can also try something like this

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["HasEditPermission"]
```

in your View and subsequent child action views as well..

Comment: I mentioned this solution in my question itself.. I want to know what is happening exactly, and is there any other way?

Comment: `Request.Params` gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items not RoutedValues.

Comment: your comment just gave me some clue and I could find a way of doing it something like ViewContext.RouteData.Values["HasEditPermission"] in View.. could you please update your answer,so that I could select as answer.. my concern with your original answer was about using ViewBag..